# Is /ʑ/ stigmatized in Wu?

Tags: topolect

The voiced alveolo-palatal sibilant fricative /ʑ/ can be found in Wu words like: *thank you*. 谢谢 is said to be read:

> [image]

> ʑia ʑia

I'm seeing many resources online [claiming](https://www.17-minute-world-languages.com/en/shanghainese/) that the reading can just be:

> 谢谢! Yá yà! Thank you!

This gives me the feeling that the inital /ʑ/ might be somewhat stigmatized, perhaps out of convenience or for other reasons.

Answer (score -1):

DEfinitely not "ya" sound, in 江浙话 (we seldon use 吴 Wu any more), "ya ya nong" will be childish way of speaking.  The closest I can think of is more on "Xia Xia Nong" side.  The headache is, like most of the major dialects in China, Wu 江浙话 also varies in pronunciation and accent from area to area, to the degree that Shanghai people do not admit 温州 dialect is part of 江浙话。  "They are villagers."

Comment: Where are you from? There is no such term as 江浙话 in linguistics. I'm wondering if it's used among a particular group of people?

Comment: I am from Shanghai.  People usually classified our dialect as 吴语, which is more academic.  In daily talking, 江浙话 (江苏 and 浙江) is used, which then divided into small area: 上海话、温州话、宁波话 ...... all with differences in accent.

Comment: "They are villagers." 也太草了[捂脸]。温州话“谢谢你”比较接近与 “they1 they1 泥” （英文的they，但是读轻声或者接近第一声）